# CSS: Horizontal scroll for each row in table

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following **markup**(using **AngularJS**):

```
             <div class="col-sm-12" id="stack-table-container" style="padding:0px">
                <table class="col-sm-12 table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="grid in grids">
                            <td class="bold" style="text-align:center;width:10% !important">    {{grid.Left}} 
                                <div>
                                    ({{grid.Count}})
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:90%">
                                <div stack-bar dataid="grid.Left.substring(0, 2)+ '_' + $index" data="grid.Inner" type="barType" companydata="grid.Count_dict">
                                    <div id="{{grid.Left.substring(0, 2)}}_{{$index}}">
                                        <svg style='height:200px'> </svg>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

I am planning to set the **SVG's width dynamically** according to the data passed to the angular directive 'stack-bar'.

As you can see each row in the table has a variable width **multibar chart** plotted using the angular directive.

The problem I am facing is that some rows may exceed the width of the table due to the SVG's(which is wrapped in the second 'td' of the row) width. Consequentially, I want such rows to have a individual horizontal scrollbars.

I tried setting a fixed width to each row and applied **overflow-x: scroll** to the second 'td' which contains the bar chart. But this doesn't work. Any suggestions on what I can do? Should I not use a table?

Comment: Did you try overflow:auto?

Comment: on what element? tr or td?

Comment: try setting it on td whose width can exceed due to SVG's width

Comment: no that didn't work.

Comment: Can you embed your code snippet here? Or maybe create a jsFiddle/Plunkr? It'll be easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, I found an alternate solution. I decided not to use a table and went with divs. Will be posting an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out **not using a table** was a good idea. Here's the new markup:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="stack-table-container" style="padding:0px">
                <div ng-repeat="grid in grids" class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top:70px;text-align:center">
                        <div>
                            <span>{{grid.Left}}</span>
                        </div> 
                        <div>
                            <span>({{grid.Count}})</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10" stack-bar dataid="grid.Left.substring(0, 2)+ '_' + $index" data="grid.Inner" type="barType" companydata="grid.Count_dict">
                        <div id="{{grid.Left.substring(0, 2)}}_{{$index}}" style="overflow-x:scroll"> //scroll here
                            <svg style='height:200px'> </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

However, I would still like to see a solution with the table!